# why this if condition is not worked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i used a if condition like this

```js
if (!$("tr[data-id='" + currenttrid + "'] > td:first-child").css("display", none)) {
  $("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child button").addClass("collapse")
}
```

but its not taken how i re arrange this code

Comment: please show your complete code in snippet as currently you have not even included `jquery.min.js` because of which we can't check

Comment: try `if (!$("tr[data-id='" + currenttrid + "'] > td:first-child:hidden")) {`

Comment: You are using `none` instead of `"none"` (it should be a string). This is also just setting the display to none and not actually checking anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the display property but you are setting it inside the if condition.

Use `.css("display")` instead of  `.css("display", none)`

```
 if ($("tr[data-id='" + currenttrid + "'] > td:first-child").css("display")!="none" ) {
            $("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child button").addClass("collapse")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want that :

```
if (!$("tr[data-id='" + currenttrid + "'] > td:first-child").is(":visible")) {
    $("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child button").addClass("collapse")
}
```

To check if an element is displayed, use *.is(":visible")*

Answer (score 0):

The `if` block is executed on based on boolean value. So the conditnal statement is evaluated to either `true` or `false` and it is executed accordingly.

You can check this

```
if (!$("tr[data-id='" + currenttrid + "'] > td:first-child").css("display")==="none")) {  // will check the condition
  $("tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child button").addClass("collapse")
}
```

alternatively you can use [**is(selector)**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like

```
if($("#someElem").is(':visible')){
 // Rest of code
}
```